# Unicode at IIS 7 on Windows 2008 Server SP2

Tags: php, unicode, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I have simple page in php which gets argument with get method. 
The page just prints the argument. Nothing more.
It works properly with english chars. If i pass as argument value in some Unicode language (etc Russian), then the value of the argument printed as question marks.

How to solve the issue?

Thank you, Yuri

P.S. adding header with utf-8 doesn't help.

this is the get: 
  mypage.php?src=uploaded_files/пока.mp3

this is the encoding: 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

and this is the output: 
  uploaded_files/????.mp3

Comment: Please show more details. Can you make an example of the GET request and the resulting output? What encoding is your page currently in?

Comment: this is the get:
mypage.php?src=uploaded_files/пока.mp3

this is the encoding:
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 

and this is the output:
uploaded_files/????.mp3

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may be that PHP does not nativley support Unicode.  From the [Strings doc page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

> A string is series of characters,
>   therefore, a character is the same as
>   a byte. That is, there are exactly 256
>   different characters possible. This
>   also implies that PHP has no native
>   support of Unicode. See utf8_encode()
>   and utf8_decode() for some basic
>   Unicode functionality.

That page reccomends if you want to use unicode that you encode it uses [utf8_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)

```
 $r = "пока.mp3"
 $s = utf8_encode($r);
```

Comment: Unortunately id made no difference. But i noticed that _SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] has Unicode value. Will try to extract it from there.

Comment: After i extract it from $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] , it switches to question marks.

Comment: I don't think raw unicode characters are supported in querystrings.  I think you would need to have them encoded in the url.

Comment: If so, why $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] contains unicode string? I can see it if i put phpinfo call on my page.